# sqoop export from local csv file to mysql proplem

Tags: hadoop, export, sqoop

sqoop export error. I searched many links but could't find solution.

```
enter code here18/12/02 22:55:46 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job: 
java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1663)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:63)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, What have you tried so far? Maybe consider making the [tour] and be sure to read the [ask] guide.

Comment: Could you please paste your sqoop script and csv file sample data?

Comment: sample data                                                                                                
1,W-03,MR. SAMI UR REHMAN,1600000,894796,1,2018

1,W-03,MR. SAMI UR REHMAN,1600000,717499,2,2018

Comment: sqoop command "sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart:3306/first_db --table test1 --username root --password cloudera  --fields-terminated-by ',' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --escaped-by '\\' --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/Tar_Rec/ICF_TAR_REC_SUM.csv"

Comment: @waleed have you created the test1 table with same schema as number of field in your csv file

Comment: yes i have created field same as csv file . the problem is this map works buts reduce not work. but some of record from csv was loaded in table ..

Comment: i solved this issue by using --direct .. but i want to know why  map reduces not work.... i want to upload data without using --direct

Comment: test1 table has all fields with data type varchar @maheshgupta

Comment: @waleedkhalid instead of using --direct just used number of mapper -m 1(--num-mapper) argument ,it will help to get rid of --direct  hope it will help  you......:)

Comment: dear i use number of mapper . its works but the issue is this .. not export all data .. and job failed.